# Stop Thread right after one Minute

Tags: java, multithreading, for-loop, interrupt, interrupt-handling

I have a JButton to invoke my thread. But what I actually want to do is to stop the thread just after the one minute!
My actionListener Method is:

```
    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    new Frame2().setVisible(true);
    Thread t=new Thread(new Frame2());

    t.start();
    }
```

My thread to run for only one minute is as follow:

```
    public void run(){
    int i;
    while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()){
        for(i=0;i<=100;i++){

            if(i==100){
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
             }
        try {
            Thread.currentThread().sleep(600);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            System.out.print("THREAD CLOSED");
           return;
        }

    }
        System.out.print("DOING THINGS BLA BLA");
    }

}
```

---

**The Problem:**
I have stopped the thread after one minute successfully, but I was not able to do anything desired in it. I just want to know that how can I achieve this in order to run the thread for only one minute and inside the thread I want to do my things! But how? Am I wrong with this approach? If, yes then what should be the right approach?

Comment: why not simply doing whatever it is you want to do, right before you call "Thread.currentThread().interrupt();" ?

Comment: You should explain what things you are going to do in this thread

Answer (score 4):

The simplest way to do what you want is to have something like the following:

```
public void run() {
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    while (System.currentTimeMillis() < startTime + 60000) {
        // do something useful
    }
}
```

"do something useful" should be a fast operation, and your thread will always last slightly longer than 1 minute (1 minute + the time of "do something useful").

Note about your original code: to stop a thread from the thread itself, no need for an interrupt: you just need to return from the `run()` method.

Comment: I am using this logic but how to get out of this while loop after the required time?

Comment: The wile loop stops after the reguire time, because System.currentTimeMillis() returns the current time each time the loop condition is evaluated.

Comment: How do I ensure that i exit out of while loop if my task is short enough and is completed before the wait time.

E.g. If "// do something useful" completes in 10 seconds, I don't want to keep running it inside the while loop - 1 minute is just maximum timeout that I want, not the "mandatory"/minimum - do I just introduce a Boolean flag to keep the status of task use "break" or is there a better way?

Answer (score 2):

To be sure that your thread will work 1 minute you need to create separate thread for that.

```
 private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
   new Frame2().setVisible(true);
   final Thread t=new Thread(new Frame2());

   t.start();
   new Thread(new Runnable() {
     @Override
     public void run() {
       TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
       t.interrupt();
     }
   }).start();
 }
```

Now regardles of what your "t" thread is doing, it will be killed after 1 minute.

Comment: If it work I will be So much thankful to you please wait for my mark!

Comment: Yes, you're right, "t" thread should check for `if (Thread.interrupted())` and then for example throw `InterruptedException` to stop execution. This is I believe most recommended option. In theory you could use deprecated `Thread.stop()` but is deprecated and you shouldn't :).